# How to wordwrap to 3 lines?

Tags: php, mysql

HI guys i want to know how to word wrap to 3 lines this is my code

```
$string = "this is a long string that i want condensed isjdjfibfhkbfhdbfsdbfsdhfbdsfhsbdhfkhvbsdhvshfsdjkvfjhjfdsffsdfsdfdsfdshfbdkhsvfvdfdhfsdvf";
echo wordwrap($string,55,"<br />\n",TRUE);
```

Comment: Please add more details and clarify your question

Comment: "fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff" **is** one word..

Comment: ok so i would like to use wordwrap, but only show 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

```
.wordwrap {  
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

Comment: i like the word wrap answer but i need to know how to only show about 3 lines of it?

Comment: add a width on the .wordwrap {width: 200px } or depending on how long you want that container to be.

Comment: I'm pretty sure width will be property you have to play around with to get to 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the text in a `div` or other block element that has style `overflow = scroll`.